# Can I reactivate my Peggle Nights in-app purchase on my new iPad without being charged again?

Tags: ios-appstore, hardware-recommendation, games

I own Peggle for iPhone and bought the Peggle Nights addon from within the app. I installed Peggle on my new iPad, but Peggle Nights isn't available.

I've seen other iOS games (like 100 Rogues) that have a "check for purchases" feature alongside "purchase", but Peggle doesn't have this. If I click "purchase", will I be charged another $4, or will the app just reactivate my purchase?

(After a few back-and-forth emails with PopCap support trying to get them to understand my question, they punted and suggested I ask Apple.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[iTunes Store: About In-App Purchases](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4009)

> If you lose your In-App Purchases
>   because apps were accidentally
>   deleted, or if you had to restore your
>   device without a backup, you may be
>   able to download some of your in app
>   purchases again for free. Not all
>   In-App Purchases are eligible for free
>   download again.
>
> - Replenishable In-App Purchases and    subscriptions cannot be downloaded again for free, and must be  repurchased. Examples include but are not limited to: extra ammo additional health, extra experience points, or other one-time services.
> - Non-replenishable In-App Purchases    and auto-renewing subscriptions can be downloaded again for free. Examples include: bonus game levels a map/city guide, a daily news subscription, or other recurring  services.
> - To download an In-App    Purchase again, you must download it from within the installed app using the same iTunes Store account name for the original In-App Purchase.

It's an addon that is not limited, ergo a *non-replenishable In-App purchase*. So I would say it has to work.

Comment: Agreed, as long as it's the same iTunes/Apple account the in-app purchase will be free. If it charges you, contact Apple and you'll get a refund, but it won't charge you.